# checking if every point in df is inside the polygon

Tags: python, pandas, shapely

I have working way to check if a specific tuple of coordinates (x and y of body position) is inside of polygon:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
body_coordinates=(df['Mean_Body_Position_x'].values[0], df['Mean_Body_Position_y'].values[0])
p1 = Point(body_coordinates)
coords = [top_right_inner, top_left_inner, bottom_left_inner, bottom_right_inner]
poly = Polygon(coords)
print(p1.within(poly))
```

Now I want to create a column in df with True or False. But I cannot find a correct way to do so. My code for right now:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
box_coords = [top_right_inner, top_left_inner, bottom_left_inner, bottom_right_inner]
poly = Polygon(box_coords)

df['Is_In_Center'] = Point(df['Mean_Body_Position_x'].values, df['Mean_Body_Position_y'].values).within(poly)
```

Upd, examples of data:

```
top_right_inner=(828.2520390091727, 760.1087652687014)
Mean_Body_Position_x=897.615198
Mean_Body_Position_y=752.755139
```

Comment: Please update your post with a sample of your data (points and polygon) to be reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`GeoPandas`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started.html) library to deal with this type of problem. It's very similar to the regular `Pandas`, but it has some extra bells and whistles for spatial operations, such as checking which rows have geometries that intersect with some other external geometry.

Here's a quick mock-up of how to use it in this case:

```py
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely

# Generating random points
num_points = 10000
xs = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=10, size=num_points)
ys = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=10, size=num_points)
ids = np.array(range(num_points))+1
pts = [shapely.geometry.Point(pt) for pt in zip(xs,ys)]

# Generating a GeoDataFrame
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'id':ids,
                        'geometry':pts})

# Creating a shapely Polygon that will be used to "query" the GeoDataFrame
query_polygon = shapely.geometry.Polygon([(2,2),(2,3),(3,3),(3,2)])

# Creating a new column that indicates which points intersect with 
# the query_polygon
gdf['intersects_polygon'] = gdf.intersects(query_polygon)
```